# Is Media queries supported by Google Apps Script?

Tags: media-queries

I am trying to make media queries work on a Google Apps Script page but it is not working.
Here my code :

```
@media screen and (max-width:640px){
body{
   background-color: blue;
}
.card{
    background:green;
  }
}
</style>
```

Any idea of what I have done wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
let output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<b>Hello, world!</b>');
output.addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
```

Adding `addMetaTag()` will make media query work for you.